# Applying FTC to Integral Equation (Spivak)

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-explanation, integral-equations

The following is an exercise from Spivak's *Calculus*:

> Find all continuous functions $f$ satisfying 
>   $$\int_0^xf(t)dt=(f(x))^2+C$$ 
>   for $C\neq 0$, assuming that $f$ has at most one zero.

I have several questions before bringing up the proof:

1. What is significant about $C\neq 0$?
2. What is significant about $f$ being continuous?
3. What is significant about $f$ having at most one root?

**Here is my proposed solution**: (Which according to the answer key, is incorrect) By FTC, we know that $(f(x)))^2$ is a differentiable function, thus $(f(x))^2+C$ is also differentiable. 
Then, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xf(t)dt & = \frac{d}{dx}\Big[(f(x))^2+C\Big]
\\ f(x) & = 2f(x)f'(x)
\\ 2f(x)f'(x)-f(x) & =0
\\ f(x)(2f'(x)-1) & =0
\end{align*}
 So either $f(x)=0$ or $f'(x)=1/2$. 
The problem states that $f(x)=0$ for only one point, so $f'(x)=1/2$ everywhere else. Since $f=\int_0^xf'(t)dt=\int_0^x(1/2)dt=x/2+C$.

However, the answer key claims that $f$ is constant? I'm pretty confused, and I didn't use all the facts that the problem gave.

Comment: Minor point here but I think you want $f(t)\ dt$ (or some other variable) inside the integral so that you don't have the same variable in your integrand and bounds

Comment: @pwerth noted, will edit.

Comment: $f(x)$ cannot be the zero function since $C \ne 0$. That answers your first question. Also note that $f(0)^2 + C = 0$

Comment: In the statement, it does not say that $f$ is differentiable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that the $C$ in your answer has nothing to do with the $C$ from the question. Furthermore, where did you read “assuming that $f$ has at most one zero”? I am looking at the third edition of Spivak's *Calculus* and I don't see it there.

Anyway, you were right when you got that $f(x)=\frac x2$. But then$$\int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt-\bigl(f(x)\bigr)^2=\frac{x^2}4-\frac{x^2}4=0,$$and $C$ is supposed to be different from $0$.

Comment: The part "assuming $f$ has at most one zero" is in the fourth edition.